# How to assert the activity running in foreground?

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing, android-uiautomator

I have a class `DeepLinkHandlerActivity` which handles all my deeplinks. In order to test it I have written the following piece of code. Cannot figure out how to test that after some period of time the activity in foreground is the desired one? Any idea how to do it?

```
class DeepLinkHandlerTest {

@Before
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun setUp() {
}

@After
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun tearDown() {
}

@get:Rule
val activityTestRule = ActivityTestRule<DeepLinkHandlerActivity>(DeepLinkHandlerActivity::class.java)

@Test
fun validalidUrlTest() {
    val url = "myapp://loadwebview"
    triggerDeeplink(url)

    Thread.sleep(5000)

    // what to do here? 
    // some form of assertion that correct activity is in foreground. 
}

private fun triggerDeeplink(url: String) {
    val intent = Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(url))
    activityTestRule.launchActivity(intent)
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a method from [android blueprint](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/TestUtils.java#L74) but I'm not sure if it works.

```
/**
 * Gets an Activity in the RESUMED stage.
 * <p>
 * This method should never be called from the Main thread. In certain situations there might
 * be more than one Activities in RESUMED stage, but only one is returned.
 * See {@link ActivityLifecycleMonitor}.
 */
public static Activity getCurrentActivity() throws IllegalStateException {
    // The array is just to wrap the Activity and be able to access it from the Runnable.
    final Activity[] resumedActivity = new Activity[1];

    getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Collection resumedActivities = ActivityLifecycleMonitorRegistry.getInstance()
                    .getActivitiesInStage(RESUMED);
            if (resumedActivities.iterator().hasNext()) {
                resumedActivity[0] = (Activity) resumedActivities.iterator().next();
            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException("No Activity in stage RESUMED");
            }
        }
    });
    return resumedActivity[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to have a static flag in each activity and trigger it on onPause and onResume method of the activity. then you can check the flag to see if the activity is in the foreground or not.

Comment: I would not recommend to use static variables, this makes testing a lot more complicated, than i used to think also

Comment: I ideally should not have to add variables just to make the activities testable. I was hoping there would be some API for this from some library.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing something like this:

https://www.codexpedia.com/android/ui-test-deep-linking-using-espresso-in-android/

Open to suggestions if there are any better way.